# Can't select from a table if the table has null values and the entity has IdClass in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Say I have a table in my DB that doesn't have a primary key (and I can't change it for reasons beyond my control).

I defined an entity for that table, and my DAO selects from the DB by that entity good.
Then I wanted more columns as ID for that table, so I added @IdClass for that entity. 
I wanted to select a row with a column that has a null value in the DB. The DAO returend null! If I removed the column definition from the class, again the select went good.

So basicly I have an entity, and a column in the table represented by that entity, that has null values in the DB. If I select via the DAO:

- If its just the entity, the select is good.
- If it also has a @IdClass, the select is not good.
- If it has a @IdClass, and *doesn't* have the column in the definition, the select is good.

Also important - I printed the select command via application.properties, and ran it in my MySQL. Even though it returned null in Java, it returned good values in the MySQL.

This is the entity, and the problematic column (maxMarkets) is in comment:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "adapter_fix")
@IdClass(AdapterFix.class)
public class AdapterFix implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;    
    @Column(name = "SENDER_COMP_ID")
    private String senderCompId;    
    @Column(name = "TARGET_COMP_ID")
    private String targetCompId;    
    @Column(name = "START_TIME")
    private Date startTime;    
    @Column(name = "END_TIME")
    private Date endTime;    
    @Column(name = "START_DAY")
    private Integer startDay;    
    @Column(name = "END_DAY")
    private Integer endDay;    
    @Column(name = "TIMEZONE")
    private String timezone;    
    @Column(name = "DATA_DICTIONARY")
    private String dataDictionary;    
    @Column(name = "HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL")
    private Integer heartbeatInterval;    
    @Column(name = "LOG_ON_TIMEOUT")
    private Integer logOnTimeout;    
    @Column(name = "RECONNECT_INTERVAL")
    private Integer reconnectInterval;    
    @Column(name = "LOG_OUT_TIMEOUT")
    private Integer logOutTimeout;    
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_LOGON")
    private Integer resetOnLogon;    
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_DISCONNECT")
    private Integer resetOnDisconnect;    
    @Column(name = "REFRESH_ON_LOGON")
    private Integer refreshOnLogon;    
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_LOGOUT")
    private Integer resetOnLogout;    
    @Column(name = "ACC_NAME")
    private String accName;    
    @Column(name = "SESSION_TYPE")
    private String sessionType;    
    @Column(name = "USER")
    private String user;    
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;    
    @Column(name = "IP_ADDRESS")
    private String ipAddress;    
    @Column(name = "PORT")
    private Integer port;    
    @Column(name = "ENCRYPTION_TYPE")
    private String encryptionType;    
    @Column(name = "MARKET_DEPT")
    private Integer marketDept;    
    /*@Column(name = "MAX_MARKETS")
    private Integer maxMarkets;*/    
    @Column(name = "STREAM_TYPES_ID")
    private Long streamTypesId;
}
```

and the DAO is:

```
@EntityScan("com.tradair.test.entities.localhost.branches.tr_dev")
public interface AdapterFixRepositoryLocalhost extends CrudRepository<AdapterFix, Long> {
    AdapterFix findById(@Param("id") Long ID);
}
```

I want to select from a few databases, so this is my config for the specific DB:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "localhostTrDevEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "localhostTrDevTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.tradair.test.dao.localhost.tr_dev"}
)
public class LocalhostJpaConfigTRDev {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("localhost.tr_dev")
    public DataSourceProperties localhostTrDevDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean(name = "localhostTrDevDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "localhost.tr_dev")
    public DataSource configurelocalhostTrDevDataSource() {
        return localhostTrDevDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "localhostTrDevEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(configurelocalhostTrDevDataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.tradair.test.entities.localhost.branches.tr_dev");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("localhostTrDevPersistenceUnit");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean(name = "localhostTrDevTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

How can I select good values AND have the problematic column?

**EDIT:** The code above is not my complete work - this is (notice I want every column to be my foreign key because the table didn't specify one):

The entity:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "adapter_fix")
@IdClass(AdapterFixPK.class)
public class AdapterFix extends AdapterFixPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "SENDER_COMP_ID")
    private String senderCompId;
    @Column(name = "TARGET_COMP_ID")
    private String targetCompId;
    @Column(name = "START_TIME")
    private Date startTime;
    @Column(name = "END_TIME")
    private Date endTime;
    @Column(name = "START_DAY")
    private Integer startDay;
    @Column(name = "END_DAY")
    private Integer endDay;
    @Column(name = "TIMEZONE")
    private String timezone;
    @Column(name = "DATA_DICTIONARY")
    private String dataDictionary;
    @Column(name = "HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL")
    private Integer heartbeatInterval;
    @Column(name = "LOG_ON_TIMEOUT")
    private Integer logOnTimeout;
    @Column(name = "RECONNECT_INTERVAL")
    private Integer reconnectInterval;
    @Column(name = "LOG_OUT_TIMEOUT")
    private Integer logOutTimeout;
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_LOGON")
    private Integer resetOnLogon;
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_DISCONNECT")
    private Integer resetOnDisconnect;
    @Column(name = "REFRESH_ON_LOGON")
    private Integer refreshOnLogon;
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_LOGOUT")
    private Integer resetOnLogout;
    @Column(name = "ACC_NAME")
    private String accName;
    @Column(name = "SESSION_TYPE")
    private String sessionType;
    @Column(name = "USER")
    private String user;
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "IP_ADDRESS")
    private String ipAddress;
    @Column(name = "PORT")
    private Integer port;
    @Column(name = "ENCRYPTION_TYPE")
    private String encryptionType;
    @Column(name = "MARKET_DEPT")
    private Integer marketDept;
    @Column(name = "MAX_MARKETS")
    private Integer maxMarkets;
    @Column(name = "STREAM_TYPES_ID")
    private Long streamTypesId;
}
```

And the PK:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class AdapterFixPK implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SENDER_COMP_ID")
    private String senderCompId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TARGET_COMP_ID")
    private String targetCompId;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "START_TIME")
    private Date startTime;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "END_TIME")
    private Date endTime;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "START_DAY")
    private Integer startDay;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "END_DAY")
    private Integer endDay;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TIMEZONE")
    private String timezone;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DATA_DICTIONARY")
    private String dataDictionary;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL")
    private Integer heartbeatInterval;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LOG_ON_TIMEOUT")
    private Integer logOnTimeout;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "RECONNECT_INTERVAL")
    private Integer reconnectInterval;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "LOG_OUT_TIMEOUT")
    private Integer logOutTimeout;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_LOGON")
    private Integer resetOnLogon;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_DISCONNECT")
    private Integer resetOnDisconnect;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "REFRESH_ON_LOGON")
    private Integer refreshOnLogon;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "RESET_ON_LOGOUT")
    private Integer resetOnLogout;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ACC_NAME")
    private String accName;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SESSION_TYPE")
    private String sessionType;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER")
    private String user;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "IP_ADDRESS")
    private String ipAddress;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PORT")
    private Integer port;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ENCRYPTION_TYPE")
    private String encryptionType;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MARKET_DEPT")
    private Integer marketDept;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MAX_MARKETS")
    private Integer maxMarkets;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "STREAM_TYPES_ID")
    private Long streamTypesId;
}
```

Comment: This is highly unclear.  I don't see any reference to `MAX_MARKETS` or `maxMarkets` anywhere else in your code.  `@IdClass` is intended to name the entity class that comprises the compound primary key for another entity.  It appears you are trying to specify that the `AdapterFix` class is its own `@IdClass`.

Comment: First of all, MAX_MARKETS doesn't need to be specified anywhere in order for the select to not work. Just commenting it causes the select to not work.
Also, I tried to create the entity AdapterFixPk, and referencing AdapterFix to AdapterFixPk. Same thing - no value returned.